# How can I reliably edit the <Version> element in a .Net SDK style .csproj file?

Tags: .net, csproj

I would like to edit the `<Version>` element in the .csproj file using a build script right before running MSBuild. In my first naive attempt I used regex and replaced `<Version>.+?</Version>` with the version I wanted to use.

One of the solutions had a .csproj file with a `<PackageReference>` that also had a nested `<Version>` element so the script updated it too which broke the build.

I plan to use an XPath query next and update the `<Version>` element that is nested below `<PropertyGroup>`.

Is this a reliable way to set the version in a build script? If not, what method is reliable?

Comment: .csproj file is xml file, so you don't need to treat it with regexp. XML/XPath functions should be fine for editing.

Comment: @kosist I'm glad I'm on the right track. Do you happen to know if it's possible that a csproj file can have more than 1 PropertyGroup element with a nested Version element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to set the Version property per-build, you can edit the `.csproj` by hand to only have the value specified in the file be the default:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <!-- Any other tags in this PropertyGroup go here... -->
    <Version Condition="'$(Version)' == ''">1.2.3</Version>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Then, when calling MSBuild, you can specify a different value for the `Version` property, e.g.:

`msbuild /p:Version=4.5.6 YourProject.csproj`

Comment: Joe, This is much better! For the projects that will produce .nupkg files I have been inserting a pre-release suffix under certain conditions. Can the /p:Version argument accept these too e.g. /p:Version=4.5.6-beta?

Comment: I believe so, yes.